# What is the difference between &vector[0] and vector.begin()?

Tags: c++, vector

This question is related with item 16 of effective stl book which states that while using vector(lets assume `vector<int>vec`) instead of array in a legacy code we must use &vec[0] instead of vec.begin() :

```
 void doSomething(const int* pInts, size_t numlnts);  
 dosomething(&vec[0],vec.size()); \\correct!! 
 dosomething(vec.begin(),vec.size()); \\ wrong!! why???
```

The book states that `vec.begin()` is not same as `&vec[0]` . Why ? What the difference between the two ?

Comment: vector::begin() produces an iterator, &vec[0] produces a pointer.  Not the same thing.

Comment: But iterator is a pointer , isn't it ?

Comment: A pointer is one type of iterator, but there are many other types of iterators which are not pointers. Although often the same terminology is used, for example, it is common to say that an iterator "points to" something when referring to the object you get when you dereference the iterator.

Comment: @AyushChaurasia: No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays. This lets you conveniently store a bunch of elements without needing to be as concerned with managing the underlying array that is the storage for your elements. A large part of the convenience of using these classes comes from the fact that they give you a bunch of methods that let you deal with the sequence without needing to deal with raw pointers, an iterator is an example of this.

`&vec[0]` is a pointer to the first element of the underlying storage that the vector is using. `vec.begin()` is an [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) that starts at the beginning of the vector. While both of these give you a way to access the elements in the sequence these are 2 distinct concepts. Search up iterators to get a better idea of how this works.

If your code supports [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) its often easiest to use the iterators to iterate over the data. Part of the reasons for this is that **iterators are not pointers**, they let you iterate over the elements of the data structure without needing to know as much about the implementation details of the datastructure you are iterating over.

However sometimes you need the raw array of items, for example in some legacy API's or calls to C code you might need to pass a pointer to the array. In this case you have no choice but to extract the raw array from the vector, you can do this using something such as `&vec[0]`. Note that if you have c++11 support there's an explicit way to do this with [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) which will give you access to the underlying storage array. The c++11 way has the additional benefit of also more clearly stating your intent to the people reading your code.

Comment: They are not. Consider iterator as wrapper (class) around pointer. You cant take address of a class object just like that. Class (iterators) facilitate features so that you can work with them just like pointers.

Comment: "What is the difference between iterators and pointers please?" "<difference between iterators and pointers>" "But aren't iterators and pointers the same?" *what*

Answer (score 4):

Formally, one produces an iterator, and the other a pointer, but I think the major difference is that `vec[0]` will do bad stuff if the vector is empty, while `vec.begin()` will not.

Comment: Taking the address of `vec[0]` is legal even for an empty array. You are allowed to point to one element beyond the end of the array, but not dereference that pointer.

Comment: @b4hand that is true for an *array*, but the OP specifically mentioned that it is a *vector*, no? Am I missing something?

Comment: @b4hand A `std::vector` is not an array. `vector::operator[]` returns a reference, which must be bound to an actual object. (Or, using the sequence container requirements: `vector::operator[]` must behave as if it performs an indirection of an iterator.)

Comment: @dyp: I think he's probably invoking that old "`&a[n]` is safe cos `&*` cancel out" nonsense.

Comment: Very late response to an old comment, but yes, I was only talking about an array, so that comment was incorrect in context. `vec[0]` is legal for an empty array, and not legal for an empty vector. I think it might be a better answer if instead of "will do bad stuff", you said "`vec[0]` results in undefined behavior if the vector is empty." Specifically, I'd give an upvote for that since it adds information that the other answers don't mention.

Answer (score 3):

`vec.begin()` has type `std::vector<int>::iterator`. `&vec[0]` has type pointer to `std::vector<int>::value_type`. These are not necessarily the same type.

It is possible that a given implementation uses pointers as the iterator implementation for a vector, but this is not guaranteed, and thus you should not rely on that assumption. In fact most implementations do provide a wrapping iterator type.

Regarding your question about pointers being iterators, this is partly true. Pointers do meet the criteria of a random access iterator, but not all iterators are pointers. And there are iterators that do not support the random access behavior of pointers.

Comment: "These are not necessarily the same type." ...afaik they are never the same type (even if `std::vector<T>::iterator` is merely a wrapper for `T*` it still is a different type)

Comment: It is possible that `std::vector<T>::iterator` is simply a typedef for `T*`, thus making them the same type. I believe the original STL was constructed using this approach; although, virtually all modern implementations use wrapper classes.

Comment: you are right, it took me some reading to convince myself, but once again my afaik was just not far enough ;)