# c++: Reason of "No instance of overloaded function"

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am trying to sort a vector of arrays using "Insertion sort" method.
But I am facing error shown at the bottom referring to these two lines:

```
vec.insert(j , vec[i]);

vec.erase(i+1);
```

complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

/*
I could do it recursively
*/
void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec );

int main(){

std::vector<int> vec = {2 , 8 , 5 , 3 , 9 , 4};

ins_sort(vec);

}

void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec ){

    for (int i = 1 ; i < vec.size() ; i++){

        if(vec[i] < vec[i-1]){ //look for a index which value is lower than vec[i], then move vec i to the index after that

            for (int j = 0 ; j <vec.size() ; j++){

                if (vec[i] < vec[j] ){

                    vec.insert(j , vec[i]);//inserting vec[i] into the right position

                    vec.erase(i+1); //erasing vec[i] which now is vec[i+1] after insertion

                    break; //ending the inner loop after finding the first greater value
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

error:
[image]

I checked syntax of inserting a vector and erasing from that, but it looks fine. I am not sure why getting this error.

Update: It got corrected by adding "vec.begin() " to the address of index as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

/*
I could do it recursively
*/
void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec );

int main(){

std::vector<int> vec = {2 , 8 , 5 , 3 , 9 , 4};

ins_sort(vec);



}

void ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec ){

    for (int i = 1 ; i < vec.size() ; i++){

        if(vec[i] < vec[i-1]){ //look for a index which value is lower than vec[i], then move vec i to the index after that

            for (int j = 0 ; j <vec.size() ; j++){

                if (vec[i] < vec[j] ){

                    vec.insert(vec.begin() + j , vec[i]);//inserting vec[i] into the right position

                    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i + 1); //erasing vec[i] which now is vec[i+1] after insertion

                    break; //ending the inner loop after finding the first greater value
                }
            }

        }
    
    }
  for (int i = 0 ; i < vec.size() ; i++){

    std::cout<<vec[i];  
}
}
```

Comment: You should learn about iterators

Comment: @MatG Plz Explain more

Comment: `int ins_sort(std::vector<int> vec ){` note that you are passing `vec` by value meaning any change inside this function will not be seen by the calling function.

Comment: insert takes an iterator for the first parameter not an index: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) the example code at the bottom of this link could help you fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty workaround:

```
vec.insert(vec.begin() + j , vec[i]);//inserting vec[i] into the right position
vec.erase(vec.begin() + i + 1); //erasing vec[i] which now is vec[i+1] after insertion
```

Also, please return the sorted vector from the `ins_sort` function

Comment: Why do I need to add vec.begin() to the begining of index?
I know it is an iterator pointing to the first element of the vector container. But why aren't "i" and "j" enough by themselves?
Is it because vectors are dynamic?

Comment: Update: This link helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510814/what-is-the-difference-between-vector0-and-vector-begin

Comment: Hi, @Max. It may be better to avoid the `insert` and `delete` methods in this as they can lead to re-allocation of the vector. It would perhaps be better to sequentially copy the elements to keep the integrity of the vector intact.